# Unlink Key frames of two objects

Tags: animation, keyframes

I made a box (BigBox) and separate it to a two objects (BigBox.001) using shortcut `P` . But when I trying to animate those two objects separately, both objects are moving together. key frames of both are linked somehow. I cant even select key-frame of one object separately ( both key frames are being selecting automatically )  How can I separate these two objects.

[image]

Comment: Try going into the Outliner, select the box concerned, open it and right-click on the "Animation" strip, select "Clear Animation".  Do this with the other if need be.

Answer (score 4):

Select one of the objects and:

- Go into the header menu > *Object > Relations > Make Single User > Object Animation*
- Or go in the *Dopesheet* window > *Action Editor* mode and press on the *New Action* button:

[image]

- Or as Edgel3D said, go to the Outliner, unfold the submenu under your object, you'll see *Animation*, right click > *Clear Animation* (in that case, the object won't even have anymore animation).

Answer (score 2):

I recreated the issue. An Action was applied to your source object by default when you add a keyframe, even if you delete the ketframe before you split the pieces in to separate objects. An Action is a container for animation key frames. Objects separated from another or duplicated share the pre-existing Action from it's source.

To remove the Action from the separated objects, select the objects, then n the Action Editor header menu bar, find this: [image] Hold a Shift Key while clicking the 'X' button. This will remove the Action from all the selected objects. In the example, the number 493 represents the quantity of objects sharing the Action, or animation. Yours will be different.

To disable the sharing of Actions when you separate, you can turn this off in User Preferences>Editing>Duplicate Data> uncheck 'Action'.